# OpenCL platform not found

Tags: c++, linux, opencl, nvidia, platform

I am trying to compile & run the OpenCL example from a book named [OpenCL in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290173) ([Source code here](http://www.manning.com/scarpino2/source_code_gnu.zip) - goto Ch1/matvec). Whenever I compile and run the program I get an error saying "Couldn't find any platforms!".

This originates from:

```
/* Identify a platform */
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
if(err < 0) {
    perror("Couldn't find any platforms");
    exit(1);
}
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit with an Nvidia Quadro FX 540 GPU.
EDIT: I know this computer has really bad specs, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You GPU does not support Nvidia CUDA, and hence does not support OpenCL.  See [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) for CUDA-capable (and hence OpenCL capable) Nvidia GPUs.  Your GPU is not on the list as it is too old.  You could try using your CPU by installing the AMD APP SDK (also works for Intel CPUs).

Comment: I thought the computer is too old - it is a spare that I installed Linux onto.

Comment: And can't I use OpenCL with the CPU aswell?

Comment: That's what chippies is suggesting. Install the AMD SDK and you can use the CPU driver. On Windows, the Intel also has a CPU driver.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the AMD SDK and now the OpenCL programs work, except when I call clGetPlatformIDs an error pops up saying:
FATAL: Module fglrx not found. (That is the short version).                                        Apparently this doesn't matter and just happens whenever OpenCL is used with (AMD APP) on an Intel CPU.

Comment: fglrx comes from the AMD GPU drivers.  I can't help any further - not a Linux user - but perhaps you can install the AMD GPU drivers even though you don't have an AMD GPU.  Look at AMD's OpenCL forum.